# How can I create a sitemap.xml to tell Googlebot crawl an updated contents?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, rss, sitemap

I have url in my website that displaya recent updated link.

```
www.example.com/recent_update_post
```

In this page, it contains about 100 links and depends on how much post updated each time, and I'm first time with sitemap.

So my question, Is doing this Google will crawl the `www.example.com/recent_update_post` and an entire links in the page, right?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

   <url>

      <loc>www.example.com/recent_update_post</loc>

      <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>

      <priority>0.8</priority>

   </url>

</urlset>
```

If not, it mean i have to create xml file dynamically every time when my content is change like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

   <url>

      <loc>www.example.com/post/1</loc>

      <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>

      <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>

      <priority>0.8</priority>

   </url>

   <url>

      <loc>www.example.com/post/2</loc>

      <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>

      <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>

      <priority>0.8</priority>

   </url>

   ...


   <url>

      <loc>www.example.com/post/100</loc>

      <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>

      <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>

      <priority>0.8</priority>

   </url>

</urlset>
```

Comment: FWIW Googlebot probably doesn't pay much attention (if any) to the `<lastmod>` and `<changefreq>` fields since they are often set incorrectly by webmasters and Googlebot can better detect this by analysing the page directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one https://github.com/pawelantczak/php-sitemap-generator
This class can be used to generate sitemaps and notify updates to search engines.